# Android Load data from Server and populate in Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have a method that loads all countries from the server. On server response i need to get all the names of the countries on the server and populate it to a Spinner. Unfortunately i am unable to get the country names from the server. This are my codes below:

```
public void loadCountry() {
mAPIService.loadCountry().enqueue(new Callback<Country>(){
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Country> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        String name = response.body().getName();
        Log.i("countryName", name);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddLocation.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, response.body().getName().indexOf(1));
        countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

}

This is my model class below:
public class Country {

```
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("pager")
@Expose
private Pager pager;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Pager getPager() {
    return pager;
}

public void setPager(Pager pager) {
    this.pager = pager;
}
```

}

Kindly help me with a solution.

Comment: "Unfortunately i am unable to get the country names from the server." Why? Does your app crash? What is the problem?

Comment: if i try to log the names the application crushes and i get java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: It seems `response.body().getName()` is returning `null`. Can you debug and observe the contents of `response` and `response.body()`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a custom adapter

or

you can try something like this

```
//assuming response.body() is an array or list
String[] names = new String[sizeOfYourArrayOrList];
int i = 0;
for(YourObject o : response.body()){
    names[i] = o.getName(); //get the name of the country
    i++;
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddLocation.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
    countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i get an error foreach not applicable to type of YourObject

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that solved my question.

```
String[] names = new String[response.body().getData().size()];
int i = 0;
for(Datum o : response.body().getData()){
    names[i] = o.getName(); //get the name of the country
    i++;
}
Log.i("country", name);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddLocation.this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```